# Ionic local notification

Tags: ionic-framework, localnotification, ngcordova

I create  a  project with ionic , in this project I read a list of data from an external json file ($http) and I want to create a local notification for each new item in this list   by using ng-cordova-localNotification.  How can I do that  ??

Comment: You can use [$cordovaLocalNotification](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) plugin. Detailed explanation is given in this [blog](http://devdactic.com/local-notifications-ionic/). Have you tried this plugin before?